# DNS stopped working (22.04)

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

UPDATE #2: The next day after booting, I enabled and started systemd-resolved, which apparently reset it to its default configuration.  Output of `resolvectl status` looks normal, and DNS now works with the stub resolver again, and life is good.

UPDATE:  I stopped and disabled the systemd-resolved service, then added a nameserver to /etc/resolv.conf and everything works.

I rebooted, and /etc/resolv.conf was gone, so I enabled systemd-resolved, and started it, and DNS is working again.

============================================

DNS stopped working on Ubuntu 22.04.  Real desktop system.  In use for 3+ years.  Normally connected to the Internet with WiFi, but tested with Ethernet cable to home router, and the same error occurs.  Other devices, laptops and phones, use the home WiFi with no issues.

Specifying a DNS server using the "@" option to the "dig" command works, e.g. `dig @1.1.1.1 askubuntu.com` gives the expected result, but plain old `dig askubuntu.com` times out as shown below at the end of the nmcli output.

I cleared the DNS cache with `sudo resolvectl flush-caches` but it made no difference.  Is there a way to reset the resolver service?

```
$ nmcli device
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION               
wlp6s0          wifi      connected               logicprobe               
ipv6leakintrf0  dummy     connected               pvpn-ipv6leak-protection 
virbr0          bridge    connected (externally)  virbr0                   
p2p-dev-wlp6s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected            --                       
enp5s0          ethernet  unavailable             --                       
lo              loopback  unmanaged               --                       

$ nmcli device show wlp6s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp6s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         8C:C6:81:9C:CD:3B
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     logicprobe
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/7
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.16.1.22/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.16.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.16.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 172.16.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

$ nmcli device show wlp6s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp6s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         8C:C6:81:9C:CD:3B
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     logicprobe
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/7
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.16.1.22/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.16.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.16.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 172.16.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

$ nmcli connection show id logicprobe
connection.id:                          logicprobe
connection.uuid:                        9093c97c-ddf8-4743-bdb0-91fd3cd67dd0
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-11-wireless
connection.interface-name:              wlp6s0
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   1686104423
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.dns-over-tls:                -1 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
802-11-wireless.ssid:                   logicprobe
802-11-wireless.mode:                   infrastructure
802-11-wireless.band:                   --
802-11-wireless.channel:                0
802-11-wireless.bssid:                  --
802-11-wireless.rate:                   0
802-11-wireless.tx-power:               0
802-11-wireless.mac-address:            --
802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address:     --
802-11-wireless.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-11-wireless.mac-address-blacklist:  --
802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization:default
802-11-wireless.mtu:                    auto
802-11-wireless.seen-bssids:            94:A6:7E:F7:2B:E4
802-11-wireless.hidden:                 no
802-11-wireless.powersave:              0 (default)
802-11-wireless.wake-on-wlan:           0x1 (default)
802-11-wireless.ap-isolation:           -1 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt:      wpa-psk
802-11-wireless-security.wep-tx-keyidx: 0
802-11-wireless-security.auth-alg:      --
802-11-wireless-security.proto:         --
802-11-wireless-security.pairwise:      --
802-11-wireless-security.group:         --
802-11-wireless-security.pmf:           0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-username: --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key0:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key1:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key2:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key3:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-flags: 0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-type:  unknown
802-11-wireless-security.psk:           <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password: <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password-flags:0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wps-method:    0x0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.fils:          0 (default)
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier:      --
ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers:               --
ipv6.method:                            disabled
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.ra-timeout:                        0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NAME:                           logicprobe
GENERAL.UUID:                           9093c97c-ddf8-4743-bdb0-91fd3cd67dd0
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        wlp6s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp6s0
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        yes
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       no
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/5
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/7
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.16.1.22/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.16.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.16.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 172.16.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 600
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 172.16.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 172.16.1.1 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        expiry = 1686104901
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 172.16.1.22
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        next_server = 172.16.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 172.16.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

$ dig @172.16.1.1 askubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> @172.16.1.1 askubuntu.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52124
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;askubuntu.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
askubuntu.com.      30  IN  A   151.101.129.69
askubuntu.com.      30  IN  A   151.101.65.69
askubuntu.com.      30  IN  A   151.101.193.69
askubuntu.com.      30  IN  A   151.101.1.69

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.1.1#53(172.16.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 06 21:20:06 CDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 95

$ dig askubuntu.com
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> askubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached
```

08-Jun-2023 added output of various commands

```
$ ip route
default via 172.16.1.1 dev wlp6s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.16.1.0/24 dev wlp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.1.22 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown

$ resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: foreign

Link 2 (enp5s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp6s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (ipv6leakintrf0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: ::1
       DNS Servers: ::1
        DNS Domain: ~.

Link 5 (virbr0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun  6 21:40 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

$ systemctl --no-pager status systemd-resolved
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-06-08 10:55:34 CDT; 27min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 1361 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 76889)
     Memory: 8.8M
        CPU: 239ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─1361 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Jun 08 11:20:57 darkroom systemd-resolved[1361]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server ::1.
Jun 08 11:21:08 darkroom systemd-resolved[1361]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server ::1.
Jun 08 11:21:27 darkroom systemd-resolved[1361]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server ::1.
Jun 08 11:21:43 darkroom systemd-resolved[1361]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server ::1.
Jun 08 11:21:43 darkroom systemd-resolved[1361]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server ::1.
Jun 08 11:21:59 darkroom systemd-resolved[1361]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server ::1.
Jun 08 11:21:59 darkroom systemd-resolved[1361]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server ::1.
Jun 08 11:22:14 darkroom systemd-resolved[1361]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server ::1.
Jun 08 11:22:14 darkroom systemd-resolved[1361]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server ::1.
Jun 08 11:22:30 darkroom systemd-resolved[1361]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server ::1.


$ sudo netstat -lntup
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1361/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2623/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2623/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1647/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1570/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1915/dnsmasq        
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      2623/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      2623/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1647/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1570/cupsd          
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           1915/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           1361/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           1915/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 172.16.1.255:137        0.0.0.0:*                           2561/nmbd           
udp        0      0 172.16.1.22:137         0.0.0.0:*                           2561/nmbd           
udp        0      0 192.168.122.255:137     0.0.0.0:*                           2561/nmbd           
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:137       0.0.0.0:*                           2561/nmbd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                           2561/nmbd           
udp        0      0 172.16.1.255:138        0.0.0.0:*                           2561/nmbd           
udp        0      0 172.16.1.22:138         0.0.0.0:*                           2561/nmbd           
udp        0      0 192.168.122.255:138     0.0.0.0:*                           2561/nmbd           
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:138       0.0.0.0:*                           2561/nmbd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                           2561/nmbd           
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           1603/chronyd        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           2560/cups-browsed   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33469           0.0.0.0:*                           1398/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           1398/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 :::47323                :::*                                1398/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                1603/chronyd        
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                1398/avahi-daemon:

$ systemd-resolve google.com
systemd-resolve: command not found

$ resolvectl query google.com
google.com: resolve call failed: All attempts to contact name servers or networks failed
```

Comment: Is it a desktop, server, virtual or real machine? Add all these in your question. Add how you connect to the internet, WiFi or Ethernet cable, home or office router. Add your network manager setting.

Comment: Edited question with requested details.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of the following commands: `ip route`, `resolvectl`, `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`, `systemctl status systemd-resolved`, `sudo netstat -lntup`, `systemd-resolve google.com`

Comment: Edited question with output of commands.

Comment: systemd-resolved status looks different on my laptop (which does not have the problem)

Comment: If you got things working, then great. Observations: `/etc/resolv.conf` in default installation is a symlink to the local stub resolver: `/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. Yours is not, but I wouldn't be surprised if this is now the case after you re-enabled & started. In the output of `resolvectl`, I don't see any IPv4 DNS servers listed for Link 2 or Link 3. If these are configured via DHCP, the DNS servers should be listed here. Are you running a VPN? Link 4 `ipv6leakintrf0` makes be suspect this. Also, Link 4 is IPv6 & DNS server is pointing to localhost.

Comment: When I stopped and disabled systemd-resolved, the /etc/resolv.conf symlink was replaced with a real file.  Later, when I re-enabled system-resolved, the file was replaced with a symlink.  I did not update my question with output from the commands now that everything is working, but clearly systemd-resolved was messed up.    Stopping and disabling it, then rebooting and enabling and starting systemd-resolved apparently restored it to its default state.  With any luck, systemd-resolved had been slowly rotting for many months and was the cause of unexplained intermittent hangs.  We'll see.

Comment: Also...  I normally run a VPN but it was not running when I issued the resolvectl command shown above.  I suspect that something was broken/stuck in the VPN/systemd-resolved setup, possibly because of corruption due to a long ago crash.  Now with the VPN running, Link 6 shows its DNS server.  With the VPN turned off, Links 5 and 6 are gone, and Link 3 (my WiFi adapter) shows my local DNS server.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am glad you figured it out. This is a question answer site. Please don't put the solution inside the question. You may answer your own question if you think it will help other. Otherwise please delete the question.